# Should "there was became" be worded differently?

Tags: grammar

I was writing a story, and I wrote the following line:

> The little wind there was became calm as the sun prepared to set.

How do I make it clear that the noun is *"The little wind there was"* rather than *"The little wind there"*?

Comment: You don't need to. Your sentence is clear enough as it stands. You could change "became calm" with "subsided" (for example), but you don't need to.

Comment: @Mick Wouldn't making that replacement make the sentence more ambiguous?

Comment: No. Your sentence is fine. How can you tell? Just invert it: "As the sun prepared to set, the little wind [that] there was became calm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a comma after *was*, for clarity. (I think some people would object to this on the grounds that "you don't put a comma after the subject in English". My take is that punctuation reflects how you speak, and when reading that aloud you might well pause after "was", though you don't have to).

Comment: I hesitated to suggest that, although I wasn't sure why.